# UIDatePicker at bottom of a modal, in iOS5 & iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, uidatepicker

In my app, I show to my users a modal with an UIDatePicker at the bottom so they can select a date. My modal has to work in portrait and in landscape. Also, my DAtePicker has to be smaller in landscape than in portrait, or it takes nearly all the screen. I'm using the following code when the screen is rotating.

```
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(datePicker.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.size.width - 216.0, datePicker.frame.size.width, 216);
}
else {
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(datePicker.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.size.height - 160.0, datePicker.frame.size.width, 160);
}
```

It does work great on iOS6 : the DatePicker is always where I want it to be. But in iOS5, the same DatePicker is in the middle of the screen on portrait mode, and off screen in the landscape mode.

Do you know a solution which works on iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autorotation mechanism has changed in iOS 6.
From [iOS 6.0 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html):

> The willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:,
>   willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, and
>   didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: methods are no longer called on any
>   view controller that makes a full-screen presentation over itself—for
>   example, presentViewController:animated:completion:. You should make
>   sure that your apps are not using these methods to manage the layout
>   of any subviews. Instead, they should use the view controller’s
>   viewWillLayoutSubviews method and adjust the layout using the view’s
>   bounds rectangle.

I think you should implement the iOS 5 specific methods to make it work.

Comment: For now, the code I posted is in a function call resizeDatePicker. This function is call by willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. This way, my function is call in iOS5 and iOS6. And if it is possible, I would like to avoid to make different resizing functions for each version of iOS. Is it?